# time differences between rows without night in R

Tags: r, time-series

A subject was measured at several time points over several days. I have a row "resptime_s" (time that the subject was answered the beep on his smartphone). Now I want to know the mean time between those (so between the rows of this column) with the night time taken out (nighttime is always from 22:30 p.m till 7:30 a.m). Take as example:

The R script:

```
 setwd("C:/Users/Hanne/Desktop/")
 dat <- read.csv(file="datnew2.csv", sep=";",header=TRUE)
 rows <- c(1:388) #time points
 columns <- c(2,60) # datum and time
 nVariables = 2
 newdata<-dat[rows,columns]
 head(newdata)
 fun2 <- function(x){
      bt <- as.integer(sub("(^\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", x))
      f <- cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(bt) < 0))
      d <- rep(as.Date("2018-01-01"), length.out = length(bt))
      bt <- as.POSIXct(paste(d, x))
      res <- sapply(split(bt, f), function(b) c(0, difftime(b[-1], b[1])))
      unname(unlist(res))
    }
fun2(newdata$resptime_s)
```

But the result isn't correct.

And with:

```
 dput(head(newdata, 30))
```

I obtained this output:
[image: printscreen]

Comment: What do you mean by taking out nighttime? I mean what is definition of night time?

Comment: The time between 10:30 p.m and 7:30 a.m.  (22h30 - 7h30).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the different functions for working with time intervals in `lubridate` gives the most elegant and easy to understand solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- tribble(
  ~time_point,    ~beeptime,
  1,             "08:30",
  2,             "11:13",
  3,             "12:08",
  4,             "17:20",
  5,             "22:47",
  6,             "7:36",
  7,             "9:40"
) %>%
  mutate(beeptime = as_datetime(hm(beeptime)))
```

**1. Define the daytime interval**

```
day <- interval(
  as_datetime(hm("07:30")),
  as_datetime(hm("22:30"))
)
```

**2. Keep daytime beeps and estimate the time (interval) between them**

```
# %--% is basically the same as interval() above.
data_interval <-
  data %>%
  filter(beeptime %within% day) %>%
  mutate(beep_interval = lag(beeptime) %--% beeptime)
```

**3. Take the average**

```
# You can use as.numeric() to extract (e.g.) minutes, which you can
# just pass to mean().
data_interval$beep_interval %>%
  as.numeric("minutes") %>%
  abs() %>%
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)

#> [1] 247.6
```

Comment: Do you know if I can load data instead of using the data frame in tribble? Because my real data consists of 388 time points.

Comment: Yes. Step 2 and 3 just assumes that beeptime is in a date time format (such as with `as_datetime()` or `as.POSIXct()`). If you have several patients, then `group_by(patient)` before computing the interval.

Comment: @MikaelPoulJohannesson Good solution. I thought OP wanted to time between beep elapsed over `night`. But it seems idea was to ignore beep itself if that happens over night.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It pastes a date that increments every time the next hour is less than the previous one. Then `difftime` works as expected.

```
fun <- function(x){
    bt <- as.integer(sub("(^\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", x))
    inx <- as.logical(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(bt) < 0)))
    d <- rep(as.Date("2018-01-01"), length.out = length(bt))
    d[inx] <- d[inx] + 1

    beeptime <- as.POSIXct(paste(d, x))
    difftime(beeptime[-1], beeptime[1])
}

fun(newdata$beeptime)
#Time differences in hours
#[1]  2.716667  3.633333  8.833333 14.283333 23.100000 25.166667
```

**Data.**

```
newdata <-
structure(list(time_point = 1:7, beeptime = structure(1:7, .Label = c("08:30", 
"11:13", "12:08", "17:20", "22:47", "7:36", "9:40"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

**Edit.**

I believe that I have missunderstood the question. The OP does not want differences between the first hour and all others. What is needed is the differences restarting from zero *every night*.

If this is the case, the following function will do it.

```
fun2 <- function(x){
    bt <- as.integer(sub("(^\\d{1,2}):.*", "\\1", x))
    f <- cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(bt) < 0))
    d <- rep(as.Date("2018-01-01"), length.out = length(bt))
    bt <- as.POSIXct(paste(d, x))

    res <- sapply(split(bt, f), function(b) c(0, difftime(b[-1], b[1])))
    unname(unlist(res))
}

fun2(newdata$beeptime)
#[1]  0.000000  2.716667  3.633333  8.833333 14.283333  0.000000  2.066667
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach could be to convert `beeptime` in offset (in seconds) from `midnight` using `lubridate` package.

We can then write a function(s) to calculate difference in time excluding night time (`22:30 - 7:30`).

Before we start solution, lets have a look for offset in seconds from midnight for `7:30 and 22:30`.

```
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(seconds(hm("7:30")))
# [1] 27000
as.numeric(seconds(hm("22:30")))
# [1] 81000
```

I have written two sets of function to calculate difference between two times:

```
# Function checks individual time and shifts them to night boundary. So that 
# time over night can be excluded. 
checkNightBoundry <- function(val){
  if(val < 27000){
    val = 27000
  } else if(val > 81000) {
    val = 81000
  }
  val
}

# Arguments are offset from midnight in seconds  
# Calculate difference between two time, excluding midtime
calcDifftime <- function(currVal, prevVal){
  diffTime <- 0
  currVal = checkNightBoundry(currVal)
  prevVal = checkNightBoundry(prevVal)

  if(currVal > prevVal){
    diffTime = currVal - prevVal 
  }else if(currVal < prevVal){
    diffTime = (81000 - prevVal) + (currVal - 27000)
  }

  diffTime
}
```

Now, use above functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(beeptimeOffset = as.numeric(seconds(hm(beeptime)))) %>%
  mutate(diffTime = mapply(calcDifftime, 
         beeptimeOffset, lag(beeptimeOffset, default = first(beeptimeOffset)))/3600) 

# timepoint  beeptime beeptimeOffset(sec) diffTime(hrs)
# 1         1    08:30          30600    0.0000000
# 2         2    11:13          40380    2.7166667
# 3         3    12:08          43680    0.9166667
# 4         4    17:20          62400    5.2000000
# 5         5    22:47          82020    5.1666667
# 6         6     7:36          27360    0.1000000
# 7         7     9:40          34800    2.0666667
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"timepoint    beeptime
1             08:30
2             11:13
3             12:08
4             17:20
5             22:47
6             7:36
7             9:40",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Two errors came up:

**Error: unexpected symbol in:**
"  # [1] 27000
  as.numeric"

**Error in UseMethod("mutate_")** : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @user9780154 There was typo in line `library(lubridate)`. I have corrected it in my answer. Have a look. I will suggest to use it 1st on sample data to understand logic.